# htaccess causing redirect loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So I migrated my app from one host to another. Most of the app works through 'pretty urls' where /login.php becomes /login (which I access in my php through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), however after switching hosts my htaccess code for this doesn't work anymore (chrome gives me a redirect loop error).

This is the code:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks  
 RewriteEngine On  

 RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

 RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]` does? it looks completely useless to me...

Comment: @Peter `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$` = Look for any connection over port 80. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]` = Rewrite everything `^(.*)$` to `http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}` and make it the `[L]` last rule, which is a `[R]` redirect. If you want to make it permanent, change [L,R] to [L,R=303] `303 is the HTTP-code for 'moved permanently'

Comment: @OCIA i understand the syntax, if there is connection on port 80, redirect it to port http://, default port (80) = useless, infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

If you want to redirect HTTPS to HTTP:

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: Edited a few times to match the source of the question a bit more (included a change to the `RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ index.php/$1`)